# setState() on root container doesn't keep routes of react-navigation (V3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a root Component (App) which renders a nested navigation as shown in the code.
Inside of app, I have the user object (stored in state) which is used by all child objects. It contains information about the groups you're in.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user: null
        }
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.user) {
            // from the login component, I make an API call to my backend.
            // If the user logs in, I do app.setState({user: loggedInUser}) from inside the LoginComponent
            return <LoginComponent app={this} />
        }
        return createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
            MainApp: {
                screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
                    StartPage: {
                        screen: ({ navigation }) => {
                            return <StartPage navigation={navigation} app={this} />
                        }
                    },
                    Groups: {
                        screen: createStackNavigator({
                            ListGroups: {
                                // When clicking on a Group from the GroupsPage, I execute:
                                // this.props.navigation.navigate('GroupDetail', { group, app })
                                // (from inside the GrousPage screen)
                                screen: ({ navigation }) => <GroupsPage navigation={navigation} app={this} />
                            },
                            GroupDetail: {
                                // Inside the GroupDetail, you can leave or join a group.
                                // If you do that, I'm making an API call and get the new user object.
                                // Then, I do this.props.navigation.getParam('app').setState({user: newUser})
                                // "app" was passed from ListGroups
                                screen: GroupDetail
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

Now, when I'd like to set the updated user (from GroupDetail via `app.setState({user: newUser})`), the navigation doesn't keep its route and goes back to StartPage.
However, what I wanted instead is to re-render GroupDetail with the new user.

How would I be able to keep the navigation state? Or do you think I have a design flaw and any idea on fixing it? Thanks!

(Yes, I'd like to keep the user object only inside of App and pass it down. Main reason is to only have few API calls)

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs, you have to persist the user navigation state.

read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html).

Comment: Hi! I have tried that. However, the async storage doesn't accept my navState (Error: [TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.])

Instead, I made a global variable holding the navState from the persistence functions (instead of storing it inside of AsyncStorage). I don't need it to be restart-persistent.

That made it work!
I'll keep it this way. If everything works fine, i'll mark your answer as solved and share the code.

Answer (score 1):

you should not create a new navigator on authentication but instead add a route to your navigator, which will be your default route and this route will take care of your login.

It should be passed a callback to set the user like this:

```
setUser = user => this.setState({user});
return <AuthPage setUser={this.setUser} /> // You also don't have to pass navigation. It will be passed automatically.
```

Inside your AuthPage you can set the user with

```
this.props.setUser(newUser);
```

and navigate to your desired route with the navigation prop or just go back to the previous route:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
Or this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

To keep user logged in you should check if the user is logged in in your Auth route and react accordingly:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const user = getUser(); // This depends on how you persist the user
    this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'App' : 'Auth');
}
```

Hope this helps.